# Viewshed plugin in QGIS doesn't work

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, viewshed

I loaded DEM and point data and as a result I just got black raster (still black after calculation). If I click intervisibility I can't see it like if line data is not there. I tried changing meters, degrees and stuff but still nothing.

Does anyone know how I can get viewshed to work?

Comment: You must make sure that the layers are in the same projection system.

Comment: I have tried that still nothing...